# How to prevent Android Studio from forcing installation of system images

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have not installed any system images and I do not want these large files. Unfortunately, Android Study keeps trying to install the images. The following is the update dialog:
[image]

In this case, I want the NDK update, but do not want the system images.  Again, I have not installed any system images.

Comment: Can't you just update the one you want via the Standalone SDK Manager?

Comment: That is what I usually do.  For this particular case, I do not see the NDK update in the standalone SDK manager.  I really want to get rid of this nuisance because it asks me to install the images whenever I start Android Studio.

Comment: Well, this is the stupidity of Google. What's nice is I'm currently having the same problem...

Comment: @AbAppletic Thank you for confirming you have the same issue.  It is good to know that my instance of Android Studio is not an outlier in this regard.